# How to add an element to a property of type List <T>?

Tags: c#, list

I use the classes `Form1.cs`,`MockProduct.cs` and `Product.cs`.
To add a new entry, I use the method:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        public Form1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
 
    
        public void AddItem ()
        {
            Product product = new Product ()
            {
                ID = 4,
                Name = "Name_4",
                Description = "Description_4"
            };
 
            MockProduct.ProductList.Add (product);
 
            var v = MockProduct.ProductList;
        }
 
    }
```

I am checking a record using the expression `MockProduct.ProductList.Count`.
Result: `MockProduct.ProductList.Count = 3`.
In other words, the entry is not added.
 
**Question.**
1. How to add an element to a property of type List ?
2. Does my code have an error?

---

**Picture-1**
 [image]

**MockProduct.cs**

```
static class MockProduct
    {
        static List<Product> productList;

        public static List<Product> ProductList
        {
            get
            {
                return productList = new List<Product>
                {
                    new Product {ID = 1, Name = "Name_1", Description = "Description_1"},
                    new Product {ID = 2, Name = "Name_2", Description = "Description_2"},
                    new Product {ID = 3, Name = "Name_3", Description = "Description_3"},
                };
            }
            set
            {
                productList = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Product.cs**

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: That's because every time you invoke the getter you create a new list and return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time, when you call getter of `ProductList` property, you'll create and initialize a new instance of `productList` field (using `new` operator), therefore you always getting `ProductList.Count` equals `3`. 
Try to move this logic outside the property and initialize `productList` only once, when declaring it

```cs
static List<Product> productList = new List<Product>
{
    new Product {ID = 1, Name = "Name_1", Description = "Description_1"},
    new Product {ID = 2, Name = "Name_2", Description = "Description_2"},
    new Product {ID = 3, Name = "Name_3", Description = "Description_3"},
};

public static List<Product> ProductList
{
    get
    {
        return productList;
    }
    set
    {
        productList = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a initial value for your list you could instantiate your list only the first time you access it:

```
get
{
    if (productList == null)
    {
        productList = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product {ID = 1, Name = "Name_1", Description = "Description_1"},
            new Product {ID = 2, Name = "Name_2", Description = "Description_2"},
            new Product {ID = 3, Name = "Name_3", Description = "Description_3"},
        };
    }
    return productList;
}
set
{
    productList = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. How to add an element to a property of type List ?

You are using the right method:

```
ProductList.Add (product);
```

2. Does my code have an error?

Yes, the getter for ProductList returns always a new list.
Remove this code from MockProduct class:

```
        public static List<Product> ProductList
        {
            get
            {
                return productList = new List<Product>
                {
                    new Product {ID = 1, Name = "Name_1", Description = "Description_1"},
                    new Product {ID = 2, Name = "Name_2", Description = "Description_2"},
                    new Product {ID = 3, Name = "Name_3", Description = "Description_3"},
                };
            }
            set
            {
                productList = value;
            }
        }
```